# UV4L WPA Enterprise server

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, uv4l

Has anyone attempted to run UV4L over a WPA-EAP type network? (i.e. University WIFI)

On my home network, UV4L works just fine. Here, on campus, it doesn't work.
(I keep getting a server not responding error).

I was finally able to connect to the WIFI by editing my `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file to add the credentials for the school's network. Although, I didn't add the certificate (if that might make a difference).

I'm just a little confused because I have access to the internet, but I cant connect to my Pi via ssh.

Comment: It's ambiguous here where the pi is and what you are trying to connect to it from.  If the scenario is (e.g.) that you have the pi with you in the library, and your laptop, and you want to connect from one to the other, a solution would be to set up one or the other as a hotspot the other can connect to.  *Unfortunately*, this probably means neither device will be able to connect to the wider network unless you add a second wifi adapter (or you can use an ethernet cable for the pi <-> laptop connection instead, which is also the simplest method).

Answer (score 1):

SSH and UV4L both use port assignments for routing. Your university network admin is likely to have blocked those ports - most people don't need to SSH into things in the library, and unnecessarily open ports are bad for security.

You should contact your university's IT department and ask what services are available on the public network.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks. Do you have any suggestions of a work around for streaming using UV4L from campus? I was thinking I could either bring a separate router to connect the pi to, or try to use my phone as a hotspot. Do you think either of these would work?

Comment: You'll need a mobile data connection (3G/4G/etc) if you want to broadcast to the internet, rather than a local network. Either a phone hotspot or a personal router should be absolutely fine for local connections. As long as you own the network, you can administer it as you see fit.